# Star tool not working properly in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, shapes, drawing, tools

I can't make proper stars. I've been playing with the Star Tool by pressing keys like CTRL + Arrow buttons, CTRL + ALT. And suddenly I got my Star Tool broken.

**What I have:**

[image]

**How it should be:**

[image]

The problem is that I got these squares inside my star...

Comment: While selecting the star tool. Click once on the working area, then u can chose the number of points in the star and inner and outer circles.

Comment: Or (I believe) you can just press the up/down keys when drawing to change the number of points.

Comment: Mamoon, Yes I can do that, but it doesn't effect my triangle when drawing dinamically (draging).

CAI When pressing Up/down keys It actually changes the number of sides.

Comment: By the way, while dragging to create the star on he screen, hold cmd on keyboard to change the distance between the outer and inner points. Let me know,

Comment: Have you also tried holding the Alt button when creating the star while dragging? It resets the distances between the ins and outs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Figured it out.

If you take the Star Tool and go all the way down to only 3 points for the star (first example below) and press Ctrl+Up Arrow Key, you will get that design. Never knew this existed.

To get out of this mode, you need to start drawing a star and press Alt+Up or Down Arrow Key.

[image]

---

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

I honestly don't know what you did back there to get those lines inside your star but I know a workaround till someone else comes with a more permanent fix for your problem.

1. Select **the star tool**
2. Click on the screen and add **5 to points section**
3. If you see the lines inside the star, select the whole star and go to **Pathfinder > Unite**
4. Change the background color to yellow and resize the star to fit your needs

[image]

Comment: It was working fine, not broken at all. Just not doing what you wanted it to do :p